# executable and linking format(elf)

Tags: c, elf

how to separate data part of an elf file using a C program

Thanks

Comment: Have you Googled? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Comment: i had read it.but i didn't understand.

Comment: Well, perhaps you shouldn't be messing with things at this level then. High-level-languages exist for a reason (that not even those who can like to mess with this stuff when not needed).

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to do, not what you think should be done?  It appears you want to get static data from compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

You can browse the source code of elfdump or use the elfio library http://elfio.sourceforge.net/